# many UNCLAIMED drivers after installing Nvidia driver Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, nvidia

I have a dual boot on separate SDDs, one fow Windows one for Ubuntu 20.4. Used it no problems for a week or so. My PC is a notebook ASUS TUF 505.

Then I tried to install the proper Nvidia driver (from drivers update), but after restart many drivers are GONE, including all network (no ethernet, neither wifi), and also the mousepad is gone.

I guess sound as well might be gone, but I didn't check as I have no internet.

I tried to run `$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-drivers-common`, but didn't solve anything.

The most important thing for me now is to get the network going...
Some information: kernel `5.13.0.27-generic`

```
lshw -c network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.

  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 15
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7904000-f7904fff memory:f7900000-f7903fff

  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7700000-f770ffff
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of: `sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: try booting in your previous (5.11?) kernel. I had problems booting my Asus laptop into the newest 5.13 kernel after an automatic upgrade

Comment: Thank you very much @FairMiles , booting in 5.11 solved every problem! in fact, kernel 5.13 was causing all the trouble. I don´t know if the installation of the latest nVidia drivers caused the kernel to update, or if it was there all along and this update in the driver caused the kernel switch. I re-installed the driver, but using an older version and now everything is running fine

Comment: Glad to know, @JuanMa53! In my case something went wrong (I don't know when exactly, but not far from the 5.11-5.13 kernel transition) with the nVidia drivers. So I tried updating them to the recommended (for my Geforce 940mx) 470 version, but then I lost access to the desktop!!! Finally after several attempts I managed to clear all the mess (at the final step by deleting the /etc/X11/Xorg.conf file), get nVidia back to the 460 version, and now I can boot into 5.13 without evident problems. So it wasn't the kernel itself…